# getting the wrong output with CUDA when using more than one block

Tags: cuda, gpu, fft

I am trying to develop an implementation of the FFT in CUDA using visual studio 2010, so far I've made it work for as far as 1024 points inside one block. The issue is that whenever I use more than one block the results for Block 1 will be ok and the others will return a wrong value (doesn't seem random, they don't change in multiple runs.) Here is my kernel

```
__device__ void FFT(int idxS,int bfsize, Complex* data1, Complex* data0, int k, int N ){
        Complex alpha;
        if((idxS % bfsize) < (bfsize/2)){
            data1[idxS] = ComplexAdd(data0[idxS],data0[idxS+bfsize/2]);
        }
        else
        {
            float angle = -PI*2*((idxS*(1<<k)%(bfsize/2)))/N;
            alpha.x = cos(angle);
            alpha.y= sin(angle);
            Complex v0;
            v0 = ComplexAdd(data0[idxS-bfsize/2] ,ComplexScale(data0[idxS],-1));
            data1[idxS] = ComplexMul(v0, alpha);
        }
       }

__device__ void Ordenador(int r, int idxS ,Complex* data1, Complex* data0 ){
    int p = 0;
    for(int k = 0;k < r;k++)
       {
          if(idxS & (1<<k))
          p+=1<<(r - k - 1);
        }
    data1[idxS] = data0[p];
    __syncthreads();
}


__global__ void GPU_FFT(int N, int r, Complex* data0, Complex* data1, int k) {
    int idxS = threadIdx.x+ blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
        __syncthreads;
        int bfsize = 1<<(r - k);
        FFT(idxS, bfsize,  data1,  data0, k, N);
        data0[idxS] = data1[idxS];
   }
int prepFFT(float *Entrada, Complex* saida, int N ){
    if(ceilf(log2((float)N)) == log2((float)N) ){
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            saida[i].x = Entrada[i];
            saida[i].y = 0;
        }
        Complex *d_saida;
        int m = (int)log2((float)N);
        Complex *data1 = new Complex[N];
        Complex *data1_d;
        if (N<1024){
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMalloc((void**)&d_saida,   sizeof(Complex) * N));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(d_saida,saida, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMalloc((void**)&data1_d,   sizeof(Complex) * N));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(data1_d,data1, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        const dim3 numThreads (N,1,1);
        const dim3 numBlocks(1,1,1);
            for(int k = 0 ;k < m ; k++)
    {
        GPU_FFT<<<numBlocks,numThreads, N*2>>>( N, m, d_saida, data1_d, k);
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
    }
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(saida,data1_d, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        }
        else{
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMalloc((void**)&d_saida,   sizeof(Complex) * N));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(d_saida,saida, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMalloc((void**)&data1_d,   sizeof(Complex) * N));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(data1_d,data1, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        const dim3 numThreads (1024,1,1);
        const dim3 numBlocks(N/1024 +1,1,1);
            for(int k = 0;k < m;k++)
    {
        GPU_FFT<<<numBlocks,numThreads, N*2>>>( N, m, d_saida, data1_d, k);
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
    }
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(saida,data1_d, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaDeviceSynchronize());     
        cudaFree(data1_d);
        cudaFree(d_saida);
        delete data1;

        }
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I've tried using Shared memory, however it would return all 0s and I figured CUDA wasn't copying from global to shared ( NSight would tell me that the value for that memory position was ????). This code should be just a proof of concept for now, doesn't have to be optimized, just return the right values. If you guys need the full code I'll provide it. I've been searching for a solution for this for over a month now, this is my desperate call.

Thanks,
John

------- Update --------

I changed the code for debugging purposes launching 2 threads in each of the 2 blocks.

```
int prepFFT(float *Entrada, Complex* saida, int N ){
    if(ceilf(log2((float)N)) == log2((float)N) ){
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            saida[i].x = Entrada[i];
            saida[i].y = 0;
        }
        Complex *d_saida;
        int m = (int)log2((float)N);

        Complex *data1 = new Complex[N];
        Complex *data1_d;

        if (N<1024){
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMalloc((void**)&d_saida,   sizeof(Complex) * N));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(d_saida,saida, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMalloc((void**)&data1_d,   sizeof(Complex) * N));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(data1_d,data1, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        const dim3 numThreads (2,1,1);
        const dim3 numBlocks(2,1,1);
            for(int k = 0 ;k < m ; k++)
    {
        GPU_FFT<<<numBlocks,numThreads, N*2>>>( N, m, d_saida, data1_d, k);
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
    }
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(saida,data1_d, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        }
        else{
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMalloc((void**)&d_saida,   sizeof(Complex) * N));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(d_saida,saida, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMalloc((void**)&data1_d,   sizeof(Complex) * N));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(data1_d,data1, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        const dim3 numThreads (1024,1,1);
        const dim3 numBlocks(N/1024 +1,1,1);
            for(int k = 0;k < m;k++)
    {
        GPU_FFT<<<numBlocks,numThreads, N*2>>>( N, m, d_saida, data1_d, k);
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 
    }
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaMemcpy(saida,data1_d, sizeof(Complex)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        HANDLE_ERROR (cudaDeviceSynchronize());     
        cudaFree(data1_d);
        cudaFree(d_saida);
        delete data1;

        }
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;

}
```

---------------------Edit 2 ---------------------

What is really weird is that when I use memcheck (in any mode) the program returns the right results.

----Final Edit ---------------

I found out that the problem was in this bit of code

```
FFT(idxS, bfsize,  data1,  data0, k, N);
data0[idxS] = data1[idxS];
```

I found out that separating the last line in a new function and calling it with the CPU produced correct results for me.
Thank you for the help!!
Best Regards!

Comment: I imagine you're doing this for learning purposes, but in case not, it seems appropriate to point out that there is a CUDA library ([cufft](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html)) that will do FFT's for you.

Comment: yes, I am doing this for learning purposes, I'll use cufft for comparison later. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You try running your code with `cuda-memcheck` in the failing case and see if it reports any access errors.

Comment: I got 65 errors all of the type, what I can't figure out is how it got to thread 317
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 4
=========     at 0x00000540 in C:/Users/John/documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/ZZZCUDAFFT1.0/ZZZCUDAFFT1.0/kernel.cu:56:GPU_FFT(int, int, float2*, float2*, int)
=========     by thread (317,0,0) in block (2,0,0)
=========     Address 0x055089e8 is out of bounds

Comment: Perhaps you should work through the indexing using thread 317 in block 2 as an example, and see if you can spot any problems with the indexing in your arrays in global memory.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but it shouldn't be launching this thread I'm launching 4 threads divided in 2 blocks. I'll give it a try and I'll let you know what happens, Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 4 threads divided into 2 blocks.  Your code appears to check if the data size (N) is 1024 or greater.  If it is 1024 or greater, it will launch at least 2 blocks, of 1024 threads each.  If your data size (N) is 2048 or larger, you will get at least 3 blocks, etc.  My guess is your data size was at least 2048 for this particular error report.

Comment: ok, I tried to input thread 317 and block 2 in nsight, but it won't even let me choose it. Nsight will block because there is no thread 317 and there is no block 2.  I'm launching 2 threads and 2 blocks for debugging purposes.

Comment: I am manually overriding this, and launching a input of 4 numbers, numblocks and numthreads with dim3(2,0,0).
debugging with 2048 was becoming to much of a fuzz...

Comment: Well the code you've posted can't launch 2 blocks of 2 threads each.  So really I have no idea what code you're running or what you're doing.  My comments are based on the code you have posted.

Comment: Sorry about that @RobertCrovella, I did that in order to debug the code... I'll update the changed code. --- I've put the update in the post

Comment: Ok, I messed up. I was launching 2048 threads, that's why I had 3 blocks and that many threads. I cleaned up my code and removed the shared memory allocation. When I use memcheck it returns the right result, however if I run without memcheck I get weird results.

Comment: "when I use memcheck it returns the right result, however if I run without memcheck I get weird results" .  This now sounds like a race condition.  running with memcheck may affect the order in which blocks are executed.  You may have a block-order dependency in your code.  Try running memcheck with the racecheck tool.  run `cuda-memcheck --help` to learn how.

Comment: I used the racecheck tool, it found 0 errors and returned the right results again

Comment: You may still have a block-order dependency.  And you do need the thread checks (in some fashion) that @rudym is discussing.

Comment: I found out what the issue was, commented it on the final edit. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The issue is that the application has a inter-warp (actually inter-block) global memory race. The problem actually stems from the line :`data1[idxS] = ComplexAdd(data0[idxS],data0[idxS+bfsize/2]);`
At this point, `idxS` is scoped to the thread correctly, but `idxS+bfSize/2` can  (and frequently will) alias to the idxS of a completely different block/thread. As a result there is a race between the read from `data0[idxS+bfSize/2]` and the write to data0[idxS] for a different thread at `data0[idxS] = data1[idxS];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should be checking your main kernel function `__global__ void GPU_FFT`for the issue

Just change it to this:

```
__global__ void GPU_FFT(int N, int r, Complex* data0, Complex* data1, int k) {
    int idxS = threadIdx.x+ blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
        int bfsize = 1<<(r - k);
        //FFT(idxS, bfsize,  data1,  data0, k, N);
        //data0[idxS] = data1[idxS];
        if (idxS  <= N) data0[idxS] = idxS;
   }
```

What happens in the second block now?

If it's OK uncomment `//FFT(idxS, bfsize,  data1,  data0, k, N);`

and change last line to:

`if (idxS  <= N) data0[idxS] = data1[idxS];`

What happens now? Still old error?

p.s. and you don't need `__syncthreads;` just after retrieving your thread indexes

upd.

```
if((idxS % bfsize) < (bfsize/2)){
__syncthreads;
...}
```

Comment: data0 is a complex so I changed to the following:
__global__ void GPU_FFT(int N, int r, Complex* data0, Complex* data1, int k) {
 int idxS = threadIdx.x+ blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
       if (idxS  <= N) 
     {
      data0[idxS].x = idxS;
    data0[idxS].y = 0;
    }
}

Comment: First part is ok, I couldnt understand your last change as [idxS] returns error

Comment: ok, did that and I still get the old error. What is really weird is that if I run it with memcheck I get the right results (tried every option, no errors)

Comment: ok, we definitely localized the problem.
try to simplify your device FFT function.

but first you can try to put __syncthreads; just after the if((idxS % bfsize) < (bfsize/2)){

I've updated the answer to clear it out

Comment: ok, here is what I've got so far: without any __syncthreads I get lots and lots of wrong output, with one inside the if a little less and with one right after finishing the if else statement I get the most I can get from the program which is half of the output is right. I'll try to simplify the function, I'm thinking of sending the bfsize calculation to the CPU, passing it as a parameter and taking the if else statement to the CPU too, so I can call half the code at a time.

Comment: with the current kernel it's impossible to pass the ifelse statement to the CPU, so I am kind of lost now.

Comment: __syncthreads() is needed when your computation in thread depends on previous computation in other thread, so you must synchronize all threads before you go on. And it's a pity I don't see these dependencies right away

Comment: Well, I'll find out a way of implementing this, perhaps I'll state it like a scatter or a gather pattern. Well, thank you for the help I learned a lot about CUDA coding here!

Comment: I found out what the issue was, commented it on the final edit. Thank you for the help.